# Returning LinkedList of uppercase Characters when given a LinkedList

Tags: java

honestly I'm just really stuck right now on this problem and don't really know how to go about this. I need to write a method where I am given a LinkedList of Characters (for example: {'a', 'A', 'd', 'X'}) and return a list of just the uppercase Characters (return: {'A', 'X'}). How do I go about writing this program?

```
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class ListExample {
public final class Node<T> {
    public final T       value;
    public       Node<T> next;

    public Node(T _value) {
        this( _value, null );
    }
    public Node(T _value, Node<T> _next) {
        value = _value;
        next  = _next;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + value;
    }
}

public static Node<Character> getUppercaseList(Node<Character> head) {
    Node<Character> tail = null;
    Node<Character> result = null;
    while(head != null) {

    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the list of characters, building up a list of uppercase ones.  If you are using Java8, then filter on the `isUpperCase()` method.